# Finding symmetric arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

I'm quite confused about the correct approach to the following problem, could someone please help me?
Consider the word "massachusetts". In this word, the letters “a” and “t” appears twice, and the letter “s” appears four
times. How many ways can you arrange all letters so that the occurrences of “a”, “t”,
and “s” are symmetric w.r.t. the middle position (7th letter among the 13 total)?
For example, “mcsstauatsshe” and “thusasesasmct” are arrangements that fit this
requirement.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete.  Were you given a particular word with which to work?

Comment: What have you tried? Please also include your attempts thus far.

Comment: I just realized that, sorry! I have edited it to include the missing statement.

Comment: Break into smaller problems.  Within the first six positions... decide how to arrange half of your a's, t's, and s's.  (*How many ways to have done that?*)  Now... after having determined that, place the others in their mirror position on the other side.  (*No choices to make here, only one option*).  Finally, in the remaining positions, arrange the remaining letters.  (*How many ways to have done that?*)  Finish the problem by multiplying the number of options at each step together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the letters "a", "t" and "s" all appear an **even** number of times in the word, it's clear that **none** of those letters can be in the middle (7th) position of the word. Now, consider the first six letters of the word. Because of symmetry, it's obvious that exactly $1$ letter "a", $1$ letter "t" and $2$ letters "s" have to be in the first half of the word. Also, after choosing the positions of the letters "a", "t", "s" in the first half of the word, the positions of the remaining letters "a", "t", "s" in the second half of the word will be determined by symmetry. So we just choose $4$ positions out of $6$ and then choose an order for the letters in those positions. The order of letters "a", "t", "s", "s" can be chosen in $\frac{4!}{2!}=12$ ways because the letter "s" appears twice. Thus, in total, there are $\binom{6}{4}\cdot12=180$ ways to choose the positions for letters "a", "t" and "s".

Now, let's choose an order for the remaining letters. There are $13$ letters in the word, and $13-8=5$ of them do not have to satisfy the symmetry requirement. Because they are distinct, they can be ordered in $5!=120$ ways.

In total, there are $180\cdot120=21600$ words which satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following:
You have 13 places to put the letters and 8 "special" letters.

1. Take half of the "special" letter (two "s", one "a", one "t") and put on four of the first six places. For this you will have
   $ \frac{6\cdot 5}{2} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 180$ ways of doing it.
2. Place the other "special" letters on the same positions on the last six places, but in reversal order (ie, put then in correspondent symmetrical position in relation of the first ones). There is only one way of doing it.
3. Put the rest of the letters in the 5 remaining places. There is $5! = 120$ ways of doing it.

Therefore, there is $180 \cdot 120 = 21600$ words that meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are ${6 \choose 4}{4! \over 2!}$ ways to arrange $a,t,s,s$ in the first six positions. Their duplicates in the last six positions are pinned down by symmetry, so 5 spots remain for $m,c,h,u,e$ and there are $5!$ ways to arrange these letters.

So there are ${6 \choose 4}{4! \over 2!}\times 5!$ arrangements.